# ExecuteScalar returns null for the query "grant connect,resource to user". Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am in a situation where i need to check whether user has been successfully granted with the access or not. but ExecuteScalar is always return null value to me. so i am not sure how can i validate the below query whether it has been successfully executed or not?

```
string query= "grant connect,resource to user";
oleDbCommand cmd = new oleDbCommand(query,conn);
object grantStatus = cmd.ExecuteScalar();    
if(grantStatus!=null)
{
response.write "Granted Access Successfully";
}
```

Though it granted access successfully for the user, grantStatus object always have null value. How can i validate this?

Comment: have a look at what execute scalar does: [ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx). it will return the first row of the results of a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: [OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) "The first column of the first row in the result set, **or a null reference if the result set is empty.**"

Comment: What is the alternate i can use in my case ?

Comment: @Selva you could just `SELECT true` in the end of your query... or conditionally if youd like. then cast the returned object back to boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExecuteScalar has no row/column value to return in case of a grant since a grant isn't a query. It is DDL (actually DCL).

Look at ExecuteNonQuery() for DDL type commands. When there is no return data. It actually returns -1.

With ExecuteScalar, you have to assume that as long as no exception was thrown, and your statement was valid, that there was no error.

What your code is missing is a try/catch as well as a using block

Rather than fully repeat myself, check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534021/257090

Comment: But most of the time ExecuteNonQuery() returns 0 as value. Can i confidentailly validate my code with 0 return value?

Comment: Please answer my other thread if you have some time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414266/executenonquery-always-returns-zero-can-i-use-this-0-value-into-my-code-for-val/26415262#26415262

Comment: Yes and no. If it IS going to return an error, it is going to throw an exception. You won't get a return value in that case. So you can only validate success, but by using the return to validate success, you are going to miss the error.

Comment: So how should i validate to confirm the query has successfuly executed?

Comment: The 3rd sentence in my answer says that. Immediately after the call returns, you can assume success. If it throws an exception, you will never get to the next line after the call, and in the exception handler, assume false.

Comment: Thank you. Same approach when i use ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: @Selva, please try this: write some SQL code that won't work, then execute it and see what happens. For example, divide by zero, grant a role that doesn't exist, try to do something you don't have permission to. Then when you observe what happens, you will reliably understand your code rather than making assumptions about what your code might do based on what others tell you. It's what the rest of us did before SO was around..